# How to replace column value in dataframes spark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

so I created students datafram from this list

```
example_scores=[('Ann', 92),('Bob',55) ]

scores_df = spark.createDataFrame(example_scores,schema=['Name','Score'])

scores_df.show()
```

I want to replace students score with a number.
for example if their score is between 51,60 when these dataframe will i want it to show
--Bob, 6-- and etc.
I want to use if statement but I dont know how to filter so much with in dataframe.
I tried regexp_replace, translate, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `when` expression to create a new column

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

example_scores=[('Ann', 92),('Bob',55) ]

scores_df = spark.createDataFrame(example_scores,schema=['Name','Score'])

result_df = scores_df.withColumn("Grade", F.when((F.col("Score")>=51) & (F.col("Score")<=60),"6").otherwise("1")).select("Name","Grade")

result_df.show()
```